# java standalone code that generates set of java files - how to do it in maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have a standalone java project that uses a struct definition file to generate a set of java files to output directory. All java source files have the same package name. Now I want to do that in Maven. Is there an option in maven plugin to generate the source and then build the jar eliminating all source files that was used to generate this source?

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is unclear, what do you mean by eliminating all source files?

Comment: i want to build a jar file with java files that are generated by the standalone program. Currently in eclipse I run the main java file it generates source files in output directory then I use eclipse export option to create a jar file for generated java files. Now I want to do this in Maven instead of using eclipse command options.

Comment: then you should google for yourself and not ask this question https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Tutorial%3A+Build+a+JAR+file+with+Maven+in+5+minutes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I create an executable JAR with dependencies using Maven?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven)

Comment: Create a build with maven-exec plugin to run your generator, maven compiler then maven jar. Something like that

Comment: used maven-exec plugin to generate the code in prepare-package phase. then built the jar with include phrase to specifically include the generated source. thanks @RC

Comment: @RamC glad you did sort it out ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idiomatic way would be to create a Maven plugin that runs the Java code that generates the Java source files.

It doesn't take too much work to create a maven plugin. Create a new maven project with a packaging of `maven-plugin` add the code generator as a dependency of the plugin. Implement a mojo that finds your struct definition file and runs your code generator. Bind the plugin goal to the generate-source phase and output the generated code to `target/generated-sources/a-name`. The plugin can add this directory as a source root to compile on the `MavenProject` object and the compiler plugin with compile the code.

You can then add your plugin to the Maven project that you want to generate the code for. Maven will run it in the `generate-sources` phase, compile the output in the `compile` phase and put the class files in a jar in the `package` phase.

https://maven.apache.org/guides/plugin/guide-java-plugin-development.html